# Flutter splash screen android more than one image

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen

hei, i have app build with flutter, i implement splashscreen on android with this code and its fully work.

style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and the launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/company" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/screen" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

but if i add one more image,its work but, after splasscreen the app force close without error notif in flutter console. so the code look like this
launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/company" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/screen" />
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/company_icon" />
</item>
```

how to fix or make it work?
thanks

Comment: i'd use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/splashscreen# instead of layerlist, you can make your splashscreen more dynamic that way+ don't have to deal with the complexities of layerlist

Comment: but, its actually just displaying widget on specific time right? not native splash screen when its first load?

Comment: user can't tell the difference and this way you can add an animation/loading screen/fadeaway/dynamic image change(load from network) easily instead of learning the arcane ways of layerlist and modifying xml elements from code etc. if you're using flutter why use an android specific pattern? this will work on iOS also

Answer (score 1):

Native Android splash screen doesn't seem to have support for multiple images. As mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen), the customizable elements are the app icon, icon background, and window background. As a workaround, you can create your own splash screen with Widgets.